# Reading JSON from decoded POST request

Tags: python, json, django, django-models

I'm trying to receive data through a webhook that is url-encoded. I decoded it using these two lines:

```
txt = request.body
decoded = json.loads(dumps(repr(parse_qs(txt))))
```

And I'm receiving this as the output:

```
{  
   b'receiver':[  
      b'1216******8'
   ],
   b'sender':[  
      b'1415******7'
   ],
   b'message':[  
      b'Something new this time'
   ],
   b'date':[  
      b'1499608381'
   ],
   b'date_utc':[  
      b'1499622781'
   ],
   b'reference':[  
      b'10273548605'
   ],
   b'id':[  
      b'476b4fc1559626d7d5e5ac4b90888173'
   ],
   b'message_id':[  
      b'7459df31559626d7d5cab31m07097860'
   ],
   b'recipient':[  
      b'1216*****8'
   ],
   b'originator':[  
      b'1415*****7'
   ],
   b'body':[  
      b'Something new this time'
   ],
   b'createdDatetime':[  
      b'2017-07-09T17:53:01+00:00'
   ]
}
```

How can I read this in Python? I've tried defining each field by its name and get the error

```
TypeError: string indices must be integers
```

But when I try to use numbers (as shown below), I simply get the first, second, third character of the output.

```
UserText.objects.create(
    id = decoded[0],
    recipient = decoded[1],
    originator = decoded[2],
    body = decoded[3],
    createdDatetime = decoded[4],
)
```

Comment: You don't need to use JSON. `parse_qs()` returns the dictionary you want.

Comment: `json.loads(json.dumps(x))` just makes a deep copy of `x`.

Comment: And passing it through repr() makes no sense at all.

Comment: Ok, I have it just going through parse_qs() now - thanks! I'm still having issues reading into the dict though. How do I deal with everything having the " b " in front of it? Do I just do `decoded["body"]`?